# After deleting a user, can I see when it last logged in?

Tags: linux, system-administration

I recently saw (using `finger`) that a user which I don't use had logged into my system. Wanting to keep my system secure, I deleted the user using the `userdel` command.

I know that `last <username>` will show the last time a user logged in. But obviously it will not show login data for the user I have deleted. Is there a way I can check to see when that user had logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last(1) command cares not that the user is deleted.  Try:

```
# last -s -30days | grep <username>
```

If you have sar(1) enabled, its process accounting can show a bit of detail.

Hint: when you deleted the user, you destroyed their shell history file.  Next time, disable the account like this:

```
# chsh -s /sbin/nologin <user>
```

and peruse their files to your satisfaction.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Unfortunately, I am getting an error that the -s arg is not valid.  I should note that I'm using Ubuntu Linux.  Is there a different arg I should use for this?

Comment: If you don't have "-s" then just ignore it:  last | grep <username> | less